# Ruby on Rails method to count multiple fields using where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, addition

In my Ruby on Rails application I am creating a cinema system, and when a user is logged on they can click "My Bookings" which will list all of their bookings. (Note, when a user books a showing they choose the amount of adult seats, child seats, senior seats, and student seats). On this page I want to display the amount of seats the user booked for that showing, so rather than saying adult seats: 1, child seats: 3, senior seats: 2, it would display seats booked: 6.

I have started to create a method to do this in booking.rb model:

```
def user_booked_seats_quantity_for_showing
    user = User.find(session[:user_id]).id
    showing = booking.showing_id
    self.where("user_id = ? and showing_id = ?", user, showing)
end
```

But am unsure how to get the method to add up the data in the attributes: adult_seats, child_seats, senior_seats, and student_seats, where the user_id is the user currently logged in and the showing_id is that particular showing.

Can anyone help?

It is also worth noting that this is for the views/bookings/index so if a user has multiple bookings it will list all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
def user_booked_seats_quantity_for_showing
  res = 0
  # assuming that a booking has a user_id to know who booked it
  recs = Booking.where("user_id = ? and showing_id = ?", booking.user_id, booking.showing_id)
  recs.each do |rec|
    res += rec.adult_seats + rec.child_seats + rec.senior_seats + rec.student_seats
  end
  res
end
```

Comment: `Booking.where().inject(0) { |memo, rec| memo + rec.child + rec.senior + rec.student }`

Comment: @jigz. can you add that as an answer please. @railsdog. I have placed that code in my booking.rb and have tried to display its result on the index view through the code: `<%= @booking.user_booked_seats_quantity_for_showing %>` but I get the error: 'NoMethodError in Bookings#index undefined method `user_booked_seats_quantity_for_showing' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So @booking must not be an instance of the Booking class. What's the controller and view code? (amend the question)

Comment: It's just an enhancement of railsdog's answer.

Comment: No there's something in your code it doesn't like, if I change your method to simply: `def user_booked_seats_quantity_for_showing "Yay" end` then the "Yay" is displayed on the form

Comment: I have tried your code @jigz. but get this error: `NoMethodError in Bookings#index undefined method 'inject' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0xa4975a0>`

Answer (score 0):

After adapting the above code by @railsdog. This worked:

```
def user_booked_seats_quantity_for_showing
    user = user_id
    showing = showing_id
    res = 0
    recs = Booking.where("user_id = ? and showing_id = ?", user,showing)
    recs.each do |rec|
        res = rec.adult_seats + rec.child_seats + rec.senior_seats + rec.student_seats
    end
    res
end
```

Comment: Cool (you posted about the time I saw that I had the field names wrong).